# react-datepicker select object range when handle select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using [`react-datepicker`](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) to building my application.

Follow my source code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/xr76olj70o

I wanna get an object with `startDate` and `endDate` when I choose a specified day like this: `{startDate: "24-07-2018", endDate: "31-07-2018"}`

My `handleSelected` function like this:

```
  handleRangeSelected = () => {
    const { startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    const range = {
      startDate: moment(startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
      endDate: moment(endDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
    }
    console.log('Range selected!', range);
  }
```

My problem is when I choose a day. At the first time, `state` seem isn's update immediately when I pick a day.

Results:

```
First time: I chose 31/07/2018, it logs result:
Range selected! {startDate: "24-07-2018", endDate: "24-07-2018"}


Second time: I chose 01/08/2018, it logs result:
Range selected! {startDate: "24-07-2018", endDate: "31-07-2018"}
```

What did I wrong here? Need your help! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your state seems to be updating correctly, but bear in mind that `setState` is async, so when you `console.log` inside your `handleRangeSelected`,
state is not updated yet.

If you want to log it as soon as it updates, you can pass a callback to your `setState` inside `handleChange`:

```
handleChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
  startDate = startDate || this.state.startDate;
  endDate = endDate || this.state.endDate;
  if (startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
    endDate = startDate;
  }
  // Pass callback to log selected range
  this.setState({ startDate, endDate }, () => {
    const range = {
      startDate: moment(this.state.startDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
      endDate: moment(this.state.endDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY")
    };
    console.log("Range selected!", range);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

React setState is asynchronous as a result there you'll face such problems,
setState takes a callback as its second argument, you can call the handleRangeSelected function in that callback

You can check https://codesandbox.io/s/011x911nyl i have just logged "state updated" in the callback, just change it to call handleRangeSelected

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit 6zkxr91njw]

You are calling `onChange` and `onSelect` in your DatePickers. they both fire at the same time so the one who set the new State is fired and the other use the old state values. I changed your code to call `handleRangeSelected` in the setState callback in `handleChange`

```
this.setState({ startDate, endDate }, this.handleRangeSelected);
```